# Vue typescript class component with vuedraggable

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable

I am having error when importing sortableJs/vuedraggable with `TS class component`.

When using `vuedraggable` with standard `JS standard component` it's working fine.

here's my vuedraggable with **standard JS component**:

```
<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
export default {
  components: {
    draggable
  },
...
```

*everything is working no error.*

here's my vuedraggable with **TS class component**:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

@Component({
  components: {
    draggable
  }
})
export default class Board extends Vue {
...
```

*here error occurred*

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuedraggable'.
>
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install @types/vuedraggable`
>   if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare
>   module 'vuedraggable

so I did :

```
npm install @types/vuedraggable
```

> npm ERR! 404  '@types/vuedraggable@latest' is not in the npm registry.

How can I use vuedraggable in a Typescript CLass Component?

Comment: So... types don't exist yet. https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/379

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local typings file and add the declarations for `vuedraggable`  as described in this [**github issue**](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/379) as a workaround until the [**PR which adds the typings to the library**](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/pull/805) gets merged.